# Storing a locator in a variable

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Python and I'm using a current Java Selenium project as sort of a learning experience converting it to Python.

In Java, I could do `By buttonSaveLoc = By.id("save-button");` Then, it's easy to use this locator since you don't need to remember the locator data, nor the strategy. Is there an equivalent in Python?

EDIT:

I'm looking for the locator and not a web element so it can be used for multiple purposes, eg find_element(LOCATOR) or expected_conditions.some_condition(LOCATOR).

EXAMPLE:

```java
// SomePageComponent.java
public class SomePageComponent extends Page {
  private static final By buttonSaveLoc = By.cssSelector("button[title='Save']");

  public void clickSaveButton() {
    clickElement(buttonSaveLoc);
  }
}

// Page.java
public class Page {
  public void clickElement(@NotNull By locator) {
    goWait().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
  }
}
```

```py
# somepagecomponent.py
class SomePageComponent(Page):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        super().__init__(ctx)
        self.button_save_loc = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[title="Save"]')

    def save(self):
        self.click_element(*self.button_save_loc)

# page.py
class Page:
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.browser = ctx.browser
        self.timeout = ctx.browser_timeout

    def click_element(self, locator):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, self.timeout)
        wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).click()

# scenario_steps.py
@when('the user saves something')
def step_impl(ctx):
    something = SomePageComponent(ctx)
    something.save()
```

The Python script fails ...

Note that in the Java example which works, wherever the locator is used, I don't need to remember the strategy to find it (by id, classname, whatever) and I don't need to remember the data (some id or css script).

Again, the reason I want the locator is for the expected condition element_to_be_clickable() which takes a locator, and not a web element. You can see its use in the snippet I posted.

Since this seemed hard to pick up on, I'm assuming I'm using this in Python entirely wrong, and there's another way in Python to do the same thing.

Comment: `find_element(LOCATOR)` or `expected_conditions(LOCATOR)` is overloaded with Web element also.

Comment: Was the issue solved?

Comment: I ended up using a Locator class with a method to yield a tuple which worked. Using a tuple by itself didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to specify a variable type:

For id:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("locator id")
```

For xpath:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath locator")
```

For css:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("css locator")
```

You can find the full list here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html
As you can see from `find_element_by_id`- `by` is already there.
To store a locator as a string use locator = "locator id", so your locators list will be just strings which you will pass when needed.

Apart from this you can use which is similar to the one you are used to when running tests on Java. The example is taken from docs link above:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
```

Comment: But this is a WebElement and not a Locator.

Comment: to store a locator as a string use `locator = "locator id"`

Comment: I've added another example. The link that I've given contains everything you will need for locating elements. I also started from doing tests on Java/C# and later switched to Python.

Comment: Okay, what kind of wizardry is this? Initially, I couldn't get it to work as I tried it with By.CSS_SELECTOR which is has a space between words. However, it worked with By.ID. Why does this work (yes, I read up on *(tup, les) but still don't see it). Is there a way to make it work with By.CSS_SELECTOR? The asterisk only works once for me. If I use that parameter as a parameter to a next method it fails. To clarify: I use a method click_something, which then calls another method doing a wait with expected_conditions and then clicks.

Comment: For id css selector would look like #save-button

Comment: Ah, no, my bad. It truly is using a CSS Selector as there is no id available: `'By.CSS_SELECTOR button[title="Click me!"]'`.

Comment: `button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[title="Click me!"]')`

Comment: Ah, yeah, I get that. But then the strategy and data are separate again. Remember, the whole point of this exercise was to get them in one variable. EXACTLY like Java.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is somewhat confusing, but the below would work the same basically...

Java

```
By buttonSaveLoc = By.id("save-button");
//re-use..
driver.findElement(buttonSaveLoc).click();
driver.findElement(buttonSaveLoc).sendKeys("abc");
```

Python

```
buttonSaveLoc = driver.find_element_by_id("save-button")
#re-use..
buttonSaveLoc.click()
buttonSaveLoc.send_keys("abc")
```

If you are looking to literally just store the locator itself then:

```
buttonSaveLoc = "save-button"
#re-use..
driver.find_element_by_id(buttonSaveLoc)
```

Comment: Your last piece of code doesn't store the locator strategy, which means you have to remember to use `find_element_by_id()` instead of for instance `find_element_by_css_selector()`. I've added an example in Java to hopefully clear this up. Admittedly, since I'm new to Python, I might be doing this completely wrong.

Comment: @Brazen.  I see what you are saying now.  I don't think there is any way you can structure it in Python in that specific way. I use C# at work and it's the same setup as Java that you show above, I never really thought about that difference.  Python doesn't behave the same way, at least not in any way I know of.